# Differences in meaning of ways used to express possession

Tags: sentence-structure, possessives

- *book of Dave* vs. *David's book*
- *assignments of Rachel* vs. *Rachel's assignments*

Are there differences between two examples of each pair?

Comment: book of Dave = Dave's book; assignments of Rachel = Rachel's assignments (no difference [meaning], both pairs)

Comment: use *of the* when subject is a thing: *king of the ring.*

Answer (score 1):

In the strict definition sense, they should be pretty much alike, but they aren't always.

Book of Dave sounds to me like Dave's book in the sense that it's a book about or written by Dave, or a book that has had something significantly to do with Dave in the past, like if Dave had brought it across a desert, or translated and then promoted it to the community.

Examples of this form not acting like this in real use:

[The Book of Eli](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1037705/) is a book that Eli holds and protects in this movie, and he seems to own the last copy of it in the world. The actual identity of the book is a secret until the end.

In the Bible, the full name of most of the books is the Book of [name]. The Book of Genesis, the Book of Judges, the Book of Isaiah, the Book of Jeremiah, and so on. The Gospels are referred to as the Gospel of [name] as well. In all of these cases, of refers to either the subject matter or the author, not the literal possession.

The assignments of Rachel sound like they could have been assigned by Rachel instead of to Rachel, as well.

More importantly, it's just more awkward unless you're attempting to give it an air of importance. In everyday and even most formal speech, [person]'s [thing] is going to be preferred.